# While running Instrumentation Test on 2 Emulators - connectedProStagingDebugAndroidTest Failed - INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK -/base.apk code is missing

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I tried to run Instrumentation test on 2 Emulators, using 2 different test suites with below shell script on CI machine which is using Jenkins to run the job.

```
startTest(){
  ./gradlew installProStagingDebug
  ./gradlew installProStagingDebugAndroidTest

 pids=
  env ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 ./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.app.appname.TestSuiteOne connectedproStagingDebugAndroidTest \
  &
  pids+=" $!"

echo "PID 1st is $pids"
  env ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5556 ./gradlew -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.app.appname.TestSuiteTwo connectedproStagingDebugAndroidTest \
   &
  pids+=" $!"

  echo "PID 2nd is $pids"

  wait $pids || { echo "there were errors" >&2; exit 1; }
  exit 0
}
```

before running the ***startTest()*** method, I am downloading ***SDK*** if its not available, and launching those emulators.

configuration of emulator is

- Memory(RAM) - 4096MB
- GPU - swiftshader_indirec (also tried **host** gpu)

With above script , i am not able to run Instrumentation test on both devices.

```
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35m> Task :app:connectedProStagingDebugAndroidTest FAILED[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mUnable to install /home/ubuntu/workspace/AndroidInstrumentationTest/app/build/outputs/apk/proStaging/debug/app-proStaging-debug.apk[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mcom.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/com.app.appnamestaging-YtqaUiatT==/base.apk code is missing[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1143)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:973)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:949)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:938)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestRunnable.run(SimpleTestRunnable.java:148)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:68)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mcom.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[Nexus_5_29(AVD) - 10] [31mFAILED [0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mcom.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/com.app.appnamestaging-YtqaUiatT==/base.apk code is missing[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:132)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35m[no message defined][0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mjava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Scanning Failed.: Package /data/app/com.app.appnamestaging-YtqaUiatT==/base.apk code is missing[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:102)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.builder.testing.BaseTestRunner.runTests(BaseTestRunner.java:204)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.lambda$doTaskAction$2(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.java:198)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceProvider.use(DeviceProvider.java:53)[0m
[05:03:33]: ▸ [35mat com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.doTaskAction(DeviceProviderInstrumentTestTask.java:188)[0m
……..
[35m67 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 52 up-to-date[0m
[05:03:35]: ▸ [35m> Task :app:mergeProjectDexProStagingDebug[0m
[05:03:36]: ▸ [35m> Task :app:mergeExtDexProStagingDebug[0m
[05:03:37]: ▸ [35m> Task :app:packageProStagingDebug[0m
[05:03:41]: ▸ [35m> Task :app:connectedProStagingDebugAndroidTest[0m
[05:03:41]: ▸ [35mStarting 0 tests on Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10[0m
[05:03:41]: ▸ [35mTests on Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'[0m
[05:03:41]: ▸ [35mcom.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10] [31mFAILED [0m
[05:03:41]: ▸
```

Sometimes  some of tests runs on my both emulator but after running 3 5 tests one of emulator stop running test and logcat shows **Process crashed.**

*On single Emulator , above script works fine.*

*Note :  I am not using shard option or any library like spoon, because tests are distributed on devices randomly, In my scenario every test class need to execute login test 1st.*

Can any one have an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this ever happen on API 23?

Comment: @yogurtearl , not yet checked that, but i don't want such dependency on API version.